# Excel: Use number from one cell to write a string in another cell

Tags: excel

I have one column in excel with numbers. I need to use that number to write a string in another cell. For example, Column A has "21" , in column B I need to write a string of 21 0's. Then there should be periods so the total number of characters=40.

```
Duration    ch
21          000000000000000000000..................
22          0000000000000000000000.................
19          0000000000000000000....................
21          000000000000000000000..................
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `REPT()` formula to do this:

Assuming your first `Duration` is in Cell `A1`

```
=REPT("0", A1) & REPT(".", 40-A1)
```

This will repeat "0" as many times as the number in `A1` and then will concatenate repeated "." until you have 40 characters.

Comment: And here I was thinking you'd need VB.  That's a neat function!

Comment: It's a cool way to make in cell charting. If you change the font to something monospaced, and have the repeated character be a pipe or something more fancy like "▌" you can get some quick in-cell charts that can be copied and pasted all over the place.

Comment: Good idea, I'll probably be using that sooner than later.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!

Comment: Another question: In the new column (with 0's and .'s) I need to have either (a) the 0's and .'s according to the "Duration" column or (b) a string from another column if this column exists. Is there a way I can use an ifelse statement with this code too? 

I have a set of data where some lines are missing and need to have 0's (hence the code above). For those lines which are not missing, they need to have the corresponding data from another column. I've used the following formula to determine if the line is missing: 
    =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(BA2,$C:$C,1,FALSE)),"Missing",BA2)

Comment: Yep. Just replace "Missing" in your formula with that `=REPT("0", A1) & REPT(".", 40-A1)` formula and you'll be good to go.